# Almost sure convergence of series of independent stable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to solve the following excercise.

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of independent stable random variables, that is $X_i \sim S_\alpha (\sigma_i,\beta_i,\mu_i)$ with $0<\alpha \leq 2$.
The series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ converges a.s. if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i$ converges and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sigma_i^{\alpha} < \infty$.

I tried to solve with the Kolmogorov's three series theorem, but I am lost. I will appreciate any suggestions and helps. Thanks!

Comment: By replacing $X_i$ with $X_i-\mu_i$ you may as well assume $\mu_i=0$. Furthermore, if you can prove convergence in probability then that is enough because then you can just apply [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763219/convergence-in-probability-of-sequence-of-independent-random-variables-implies-a?rq=1). To prove convergence in probability of the given series, just use stability of the $X_i$ to get the distribution of $\sum_1^n X_i$, then use the given condition on $\sigma_i$. Conversely... well, you can do it. Someone may please elaborate using the full CF argument.